# Firefox: view raw JSON on network tab

Tags: json, debugging, firefox

I'm having a problem with Firefox's debugging panel, spcecifically on the Network tab; when a POST request sends some JSON, it shows the request body inside a tree-like viewer; while this viewer is cute and everything, I actually need to copy and paste the *actual* raw JSON text into another tool.

There doesn't seem to view the actual JSON request from this panel. Does someone know of some way of viewing the actual RAW JSON inside it?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

After some fumbling around, I found out that if you right-click the request, the browser gives you the option to copy the post data (which would return the JSON, if it is a POST) or to "Edit and resend", which would open a dialog that, among other things, has the JSON itself.

Comment: Good answer, but totally crap that you have to do this just to copy the json.